# How can I configure a tilemap server in Kibana at AWS Elasticsearch?

Tags: kibana, aws-elasticsearch, mapserver

Is it possible to configure an external or privatly hosted tilemap server in Kibana of AWS Elasticsearch? My goal is to have zoom levels beyond level 7 (the current max in AES Kibana). According to the config page at elastic.co (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html) I should modify `map.tilemap.url` but this config is not available in the Kibana "Advanced Settings".

Is there any way of configuring a tile server within AWS Elasticsearch?